# Need to permute list with order mattering after first two elements

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

Suppose `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` ...

I need to generate the following combinations/permutations from this list (in general, the list could have. more elements):

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'c', 'd', 'b']
['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'd', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'd', 'b', 'a']
```

So, for the first two positions in the list order does not matter, although I need to take all combinations of list elements, while in the last two (or `n`) positions of the list order does matter. I've tried various combinations of using `permutations` and `combinations` from `itertools`, all with no success (I dare not post my code for fear of embarrassment).

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting either, but don't edit the question to ask about it - use the comments instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct solution using the existing `itertools` library functions is to select the first two elements as a combination, and then the rest as a permutation of the remaining elements:

```py
import itertools

def partly_unordered_permutations(lst, k):
    elems = set(lst)
    for c in itertools.combinations(lst, k):
        for d in itertools.permutations(elems - set(c)):
            yield c + d
```

Usage:

```py
>>> for p in partly_unordered_permutations('abcd', 2):
...     print(p)
... 
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'b')
('a', 'd', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'd', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'c', 'a', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'a')
('b', 'd', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'd', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'd', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'd', 'b', 'a')
```